# How to match 0x2102 in AWK

Tags: carriage-return

I am trying to match 0x2102 using AWK but it doesn't seem to work well. See my code:

Line in a file: "Configuration Register is 0x2102"

Part of AWK Code:

```
awk '{if ($4 == "0x2102") {print "Match"}}'
```

or:

```
awk '{if ($4 == 0x2102) {print "Match"}}'
```

I can easily match strings or decimals but hex doesn't work. Any help is highly appreciated. Already tried searching for similar concerns but unable to find one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure? I copied your first code snippet and it works fine. Check if `$4` contains the correct value (maybe you have some strange (=non breaking) whitespace chars in your input)

Comment: `\r\n` line ending, perhaps?

Comment: Could you please try following once `awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");if($4=="0x2102"){print "Match"}}' Input_file` and let us know, this  is removing control M characters from line and then running your attempted code.

Comment: awk '{gsub(/\r/,"");if($4=="0x2102"){print "Match"}}' - this one seems to work! Thanks!

Comment: Update:

I matched \r in my if statement and it worked to!

awk '{if ($4 == "0x2102\r") {print "Match"}}'

Thanks for the idea guys. Appreciate it.

Comment: You could regex match it: `$4~/^0x2012\r?$/{print "Match"}`